# Creating marker on map using Folium results in blank HTML page

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I tried to create a Map using folium library in python3. It work's fine until i add a Marker to the map. On adding Marker the output results in just a blank HTML page.

```
import folium

map = folium.Map(location=[20.59,78.96], tiles = "Mapbox Bright")

folium.Marker([26.80,80.76],popup="Hey, It's Moradabad").add_to(map)
map.save("mapOutput.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MCO is absolutely correct.

I like to leverage [html.escape()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) to handle the problem characters like so

```
import folium
import html

map = folium.Map(location=[20.59,78.96], tiles = "Mapbox Bright")

folium.Marker([26.80,80.76],popup=html.escape("Hey, It's Moradabad")).add_to(map)
map.save("mapOutput.html")
```

Comment: that is great to know, thank you. this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

in my experience, folium is very sensitive to single quotes (`'`).

The reason being, folium generates javascript, and transforms your strings into javascript strings, which it encloses with single quotes. It does, however, not escape any single quotes contained in the string (not even sure if that's possible in js), so having a single quote in the string has the same effect as not closing a string in python.

Solution: Replace all single quotes in your strings with backticks (`) or (better) use @Bob Haffner's answer.

---

Edit: out of sheer coincidence i stumbled over another solution just now. Apparently `folium.Popup` has an argument `parse_html`. Use it like this:

```
folium.Marker([x,y], popup=folium.Popup("Foo'Bar",parse_html=True)).add_to(map)
```

however, i could not make it work without running into a unicodeescape error. nonetheless it exists, supposedly for this purpose, and might work for you.

---

Edit 2: As i've been told on github, this issue will be fixed in the next release. Ref: [folium#962](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/962)

Comment: It was the single quote that was causing problem! Thanks