# Why does add_child method does not work in my geo-mapping code using folium library?

Tags: python, addchild, folium

I was trying to create a map using OSM and the following code was working fine until I used the **add_child** method.

```
import folium

map=folium.Map(location=[38.58,-99.09],zoom_start=6, tiles= "Mapbox Bright")
fg= folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[38,-99], popup="Hi, I'm a marker", icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
map.add_child(fg)
map.save("Map0.html")
```

Thanks, in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'll need to know what went wrong before we can help you. Was there an error message, or was the output just different from what you expected? Please edit your question to include the details.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Actually the code was compiled successfully but the HTML file which was created ("Map0.html") is not loading in the web browser. The file opens but it's totally blank.

Comment: Do any JavaScript errors appear in the browser's development tools? (They would appear on the "Console" tab.)

Comment: i'm pretty sure you ran into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063335/. does it fail when you remove the single quote in "Hi, I'm a marker"?

Comment: @MCO Yes you're right. Thanks