# Adding markers to a Folium Map

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, folium

I'm trying to add markers to a Folium Map of a city using the latitudes and longitudes from columns of a Pandas dataframe. But, all I get is an empty map as a result and no errors.

I've tried it using a for loop to iterate over the rows of the datframe and adding the markers for each item into the map, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
f_map = folium.Map([-35.2809, 149.1300], zoom_start=12)
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['location.lng'], row['location.lat']], popup=row['name']).add_to(f_map)
f_map
```

I'm a novice with Folium. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try it without the popup and if it works you might have a funky char in `name`.  Check out this answer for a resolution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52099491/3437504

Comment: @BobHaffner Yes! That worked. Any way to get around that? I really need to have the name in there to somehow distinguish the markers.

Comment: yes, check that link out

Answer (score 3):

Another way not mentioned by @bob 
I used:

```
dataframe.apply(lambda row:folium.CircleMarker(location=[row["lat"], row["lon"]], 
                                              radius=10, popup=row['name'])
                                             .add_to(f_map), axis=1)
```

I assume dataframe is a df of points and a label

```
dataframe
lat   lon    name
2     51     'a point'
```